# controller not passing values correctly to route.php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hey guys i have the following code in my AccountController.php file

```
if($create){

                    Mail::send('emails.auth.activate' , array( 'link' => URL::route('account-activate' , $code) , 'username' => $username ) , function($message) use ($create) {
                            $message->to($create->email , $create->username)->subject('Activate your account');
                    });

                    return Redirect::route('home')
                            ->with('global' , 'your account has been created! we have sent you an email to activate you account ');
                }
```

now this part in the above code :

```
array( 'link' => URL::route('account-activate' , $code)
```

is suppose to send the $code value to :

```
Route::get('/account/activate/{code}', array(
            'as' => 'account-activate',
            'uses' => 'AccountController@getActivate'
        ));
```

in route.php.

and as you can see the getActivate method is getting called from AccountController which is as follows :

```
 public function getActivate($code){
       echo  $code
}
```

The value that gets echoed is {code} rather than the actual value of $code .

What exactly am i missing here . i have gone through like the same tutorial 2-3 times and i'am doing exactly as the guy types it out , so i really don't know what i am missing . i checked my syntex too and everything seems to be fine . i have errors enabled in laravel .

Why is my controller unable to pass the value correctly ??.

Comment: how about `echo $code;` before passed into `getActivate($code)`. Did you get correct result? I'm pretty sure you can not do `echo $code` without `;`

Comment: @ColourDalnet echo code in route.php ??

Comment: @ColourDalnet There was a small syntex error , will post the answer in a short while .

Comment: No, inside `AccountController.php` in `if($create)` clause.

Comment: @Tenali_raman If it was just a syntax error / typo don't answer the question. The question will be closed in a short while...